# Use dynamic library in dynamic library

Tags: qt, .so, .profile

I am always using QDesignerCustomWidgetInteface. I want to use two kinds of CustomWidget in another CustomWidget to combine two of them so that I need not to write some codes again.

So I write codes as below in project file:

```
LIBS +=-L./debug -lxzquxianplugin
LIBS +=-L./debug -lxzyctextplugin
```

When I finished the code I debug the codes in creator and started debugging designer. Designer ran well and recognized my new CustomWidget. But when I entered bin/gcc/debug folder and ran executable app Designer that debug mode produced directly without codes and Qt creator, Designer showed that could not find shared library: `libxzquxianplugin.so`.

I tried to use codes as below:

```
Debug {
    LIBS +=absolute path way of xzquxianplugin
    LIBS +=absolute path way of xzyctextplugin
}
```

But it still failed to find dynamic library when I ran Designer in debug folders. I cannot understand why it happened.

Answer (score 1):

the `libs` -L switch is used when you want to add a directory to linker search path, you used:

```
LIBS +=-L. /debug -lxzquxianplugin
```

Which actually breaks your path because of the space after `-L.`

So you should have

```
LIBS +=-L./debug -lxzquxianplugin
```

given that your lib exists under debug folder.